# How do I find out what type of locking a table has?

Tags: sql-server-2005, deadlock

I'm getting alot of deadlocks on a table.
It is SQL Server 2005

the sp that is getting the error does the following

```
Delete From
    EmployeeAccrualAdj 
Where
    EmployeeID = @iEmployeeID and 
    SchemeCode = @sSchemeCode and
    AdjTypeCode = @sAdjTypeCode and
    EffectiveDate >= @dtDateFrom
```

I'm trying to work out if the database is doing row, page or table locking when deleting?

Also, I am thinking of re-writing the sp to

```
declare @ToDelete table (id int IDENTITY(1,1),
                         AccrualAdjID int NOT NULL)


insert into @ToDelete
SELECT 
    AccrualAdjID
FROM 
    EmployeeAccrualAdj
Where
    EmployeeID = @iEmployeeID and 
    SchemeCode = @sSchemeCode and
    AdjTypeCode = @sAdjTypeCode and
    EffectiveDate >= @dtDateFrom


DECLARE @iCount int, @iMax int
SELECT 
    @iCount = 1, @iMax = MAX(id)
FROM 
    @ToDelete

declare @iAccrualAdjID int

WHILE @iCount <= @iMax
BEGIN

    select @iAccrualAdjID = AccrualAdjID FROM @ToDelete WHERE id = @iCount

    DELETE FROM EmployeeAccrualAdj
    WHERE @iAccrualAdjID = AccrualAdjID


    SET @iCOunt = @iCount + 1
END
```

Effectivly looping through the rows to be deleted and deleting them one at a time.

I'm thinking  this will not make any difference if there is row locking , but will if there is page or table locking
What do you all reckon??

Comment: The error message we are gettign is 
Transaction (Process ID 51) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. (Error executing stored procedure: Employee_AccrualAdjustments_Delete @iEmployeeID = 510337, @sSchemeCode = ''SAH'', @sAdjTypeCode = ''A'', @dtDateFrom = ''2008-09-20T00:00:00'')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the [lock escalation rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/05/17/Lock-escalation.aspx).  The cursor-based approach you are wondering about will be amazingly slow if you have very many rows.  I'd look into what other queries are hitting that table during the `DELETE` operation and see whether you can block them for the duration of the delete with a preemptive lock acquisition.

[This article](http://mikedimmick.blogspot.com/2004/03/selectupdate-problem-or-why-updlock.html) gives an example of how to acquire the needed locks up front with an `UPDLOCK` locking hint.